# Program, Site or plugin to find a RGB code in an existing image file to see the location of the RGB

Tags: rgb, games, search

I have a .bmp image file containing about 3000 unique RGBs to make tiles for a game, the game has a separate file defining the RGB of the tile but when working with them it can be hard to pin down that unique RGB without knowing where it appears in the.bmp file.
Example of the province.bmp:
[image]

Example of the definition.csv:

```
province;red;green;blue;x;x
1;204;229;152;Sitka;x
2;204;179;153;Yakutat;x
3;153;230;153;Kenai;x
4;192;0;0;Dutch Harbor;x
5;192;0;128;Unalakleet;x
6;153;179;153;Whitehorse;x
7;192;128;128;Dawson;x
8;179;204;153;Ross River;x
9;128;64;128;Fort Simpson;x
10;64;128;128;Inuvik;x
```

Often to find the province I simply put the RGB in a random pixel and then select all of that color but I was wondering if there was a more automized way of it. I personally use Paint.net or GIMP for image editing.

Comment: You can select by color, but yhe indicator is a bit weak.

Comment: You could write a script to go through each pixel and categorize it into a color grouping. I'm not sure what your end goal is with the data so not sure if that's applicable